# How do I modify this .htaccess?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Im using laravel and I have a dev environment and production env. I want to hide the `public` folder from the URL. In my production everything works fine, where the root url is www.example.com, and the .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

However, in my dev env, im using a url for laravel like this: www.example.com/dev, where `dev` is the root. The above .htaccess no longer works with the subdirectory as the root dir, can you guys help me modify it?

PS. The .htaccess also enforces HTTPS but thats not the point.

Comment: Would `RewriteBase /dev` help?

Comment: no, sorry it didnt help

Comment: i don't get it why is your dev the root ?

isn't that your domain should be your root  already

Comment: dev is root because its dev, i dont want to buy a domain to develop on. so im using my existing domain.

Comment: Are your "dev" and "production" environments the _same_ server and the "dev" site is simply in a "dev" subdirectory? ie. `/public/dev/<path>`?

Comment: no, dev is on a different domain